# How to set FilterExpression on DataSet defined in code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataset

I am trying to create a filter for a GridView where you enter a Last Name into a text box, then click a button which on click should then filter the GridView based on the Last Name column in the datasource.

So I was going to add a FilterExpression to the DataSource of the GridView once the button is clicked. However, the intellisense is not picking up the .FilterExpression so I know I'm missing something. The DataSet for the GridView is defined in the code-behind programatically, and I'm used to using the .FilterExpression on a DataSource defined on the .aspx page.

**Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
      databind();
     }
}
private void databind()
    {
        try
        {
            customerBE = new CustomerBE();
            customerBE.UserID = 0;
            dset = new DataSet();
            customerBL = new CustomerBL();
            dset = customerBL.GetUserDetails(customerBE);
            gridViewCreateUser.DataSource = dset;
            gridViewCreateUser.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

**So what I'm looking to do is something like:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dset.FilterExpression = ("LastName=" + textbox1.Text);
}
```

**Is it possible to use .FilterExpression or something similar in this instance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in your case, but you can use a .Select on a datatable. You can substitute in the index of the table in the dataset for whatever the index or name is.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dset.Tables[0].Select("LastName=" + textbox1.Text).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this set me in the right direction, using a DataTable. I ended up using a DataView off of the DataTable as follows:
            `DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];

            DataView view = new DataView(dt);
            view.RowFilter = "LastName='" + textbox1.Text + "'";`